# How to replicate home button double tap effect on click of a button?

Tags: ios

In IOS, when we double tap the home button, it lift's the current app and shows all the app that are running on the bottom. I can scroll the bottom and select the music player option from there. I want to achieve the same screen lift effect, when user taps a button from withing the app instead of double tapping the home button. Is it possible to that? If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: It is not possible, primarily because it produces unexpected behavior in your app. The end user will get confused when such behavior is provided from within the app.

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke the app-switcher UI programmatically, or how to replicate the "screen lifting" visual effect? The former is not possible with public API; for the latter, some [UIView animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131) should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the home button function (unless jailbroken) cannot be re-created inside your UI.

Also since iOS6 users can opt to have Guided Access enabled, if that button where to be created would be considered useless. Now that would be a pain to do in a de-bugging process.

You would have to access the Home Button API (if there was one) as well as the guided access API.